# Google apps script: How to create a downloadable html file?

Tags: google-apps-script

Starting with 'google apps script'. I've created a simple script that logs some information with 'Logger.log("message");' with this lines being in a loop, so the log message is quite large.

I'd like now to create an html file with that same information and either being able to download that file locally or have it downloaded to my google drive.

Any idea how that could be achieved? I've tried looking examples for a while but I cannot have anything working...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you should read first. Have a look [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename-content-mimetype)

```
function createMyHTMLlog()
{
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('ff');// ff:your folder name on drive

  if (folders.hasNext()) 
  {
    var folder = folders.next(); //select the folder
    folder.createFile('Log','<b> your message here </b>', MimeType.HTML); //create the file
  }
}
```

**Update:** Add more content later

```
function logUpdate()
{
  var children = folder.getFilesByName('Log');// log is the created file name
  if (children.hasNext()) 
  {
   var file = children.next();
   var logContent = file.getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();// get available msg
   logContent = logContent.concat('<br>your<b> updated message </b> here'); // combine with new msg
   file.setContent(logContent);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi iJay, almost there...

And how could I add more html text to that file once created? I couldn't find a method to do that?

Comment: Hi @mickael, I updated the answer. I must say that you are a lazy developer :P

Comment: Thanks iJay. 

I'm not a developer, just trying to do a few things for personal use but it's quite challenging!! Thanks for the help, I still don't have it fully working but it's a start... 

What I'm trying to do is a script that when run creates a folder tree of my google drive. When run at present, it keeps failing with: "Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."

I need to spend more time seeing what's the problem :(

Comment: I can't make it work :(
This is what I've got so far... http://pasted.co/56edab2e

but in the section for //FOLDERS and //FILES, I don't know how I can add the information that I'm outputting in the Logger to the html file created under the variable 'd'? 

Could you please have a look when you've got the chance and see hos that could be amended? Thank you!!

Comment: This is a different question, Ask a new question pasting your code